# Is there a way to use a var in @get from the retrofitApi?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I have this code :

```
package com.example.finalv2.networking

import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET
import com.example.finalv2.it1



private var argument: String = it1
interface RetrofitAPI {
    @GET(argument)
    fun getInformations(): Call<ArrayList<Information>>

}
```

And I want to use my var argument but retrofit wants a const. How to do ?

Comment: Annotations paramters need to be compile time constants. That's not retrofit, is the kotlin compiler. If you need to perform a GET on a URL you will know only at compile time, you can't use Retrofit. You can stick with okHttp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotations values are resolved statically, which means they have to be constant. You can pass the variable argument url using `@Url` annotation for the function argument.

```
interface RetrofitAPI {
    @GET
    fun getInformations(@Url url: String): Call<ArrayList<Information>>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding a @Path annotation param in the function call, as follows:

```
@GET("/image/{argument}")
fun getInformations(@Path("argument") argument: String): Call<ArrayList<Information>>
```

For instance, if the function is called as:

```
getInformations("abc")
```

the final URL to which the request will be dispatched shall be

```
BASE_URL +"/image/abc"
```

To know more check out this official documentation webpage,
https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html